# Json Placeholder API - fetching photos for specific user

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm having a little problem with filter in my android app because I'm using [JsonPlaceholderApi](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com), and I want to fetch photos for specific user and the problem is that you first need to fetch albums for user and then somewhat filter those photos which album id's we get with the request for albums. I managed to get the photos for first album but I have problem getting rest here is the code right now:

```
        viewModelScope.launch {
            var getAlbums = PostsApi.photosService.getUserAlbumsAsyncWithId(userId)
            var getPhotos = PostsApi.photosService.getAllPhotosAsync()

            try {
                val albumsForUser= getAlbums.await()
                Log.d("ImgRequest-albums", albumsForUser.toString())
                val photosResult = getPhotos.await()
                    .filter { list -> list.albumId == albumsForUser[1].id }
                Log.d("ImgRequest-photos", photosResult.toString())
                _selectedUserPhotos.value = photosResult
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _selectedUserPhotos.value = ArrayList()
            }
        }


    }
```

How to filter more of them, is there any stream option I don't know about? Or maybe make some dynamic request to the api?

Answer (score 0):

Answer I figure out is to change the filter to:

```
.filter { list -> list.albumId in albumsForUser[0].id..albumsForUser[albumsForUser.size-1].id}
```

Don't know if it's 100% good solution but it works :)